# jQuery not working after Updatepanel Refresh

Tags: jquery, asp.net, updatepanel

Can anyone clarify me how can I call the function after update panel refresh. I have read the reference through this [link](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/jQuery-Plugins-not-working-after-ASPNet-AJAX-UpdatePanel-Partial-PostBack-or-when-Asynchronous-request-is-over.aspx), but I don't know what to give in the `call function here` place.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type = "text/javascript">
        var jq5 = $.noConflict(true);
        jq5(document).ready(function () {
            var CheckAll = jq5("#chkAll").click(function () {
                if (this.checked) {
                    jq5('.chk').attr('checked', this.checked);
                }
                else {
                    jq5('.chk').attr('checked', this.checked = false);
                }
            });
            jq5(".chk").click(function () {
                if (jq5(".chk").length == jq5(".chk:checked").length) {
                    jq5("#chkAll").attr("checked", "checked");
                } else {
                    jq5("#chkAll").removeAttr("checked");
                }
            });
        });

    var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
    if (prm != null) {
        prm.add_endRequest(function (sender, e) {
            if (sender._postBackSettings.panelsToUpdate != null) {
                // call function here...
            }
        });
    };
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add event listener after the update panel request every time.

```
var jq5 = $.noConflict(true);
jq5(document).ready(function () {
        AddClickEvent();
});

var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
if (prm != null) {
    prm.add_endRequest(function (sender, e) {

        AddClickEvent();

        if (sender._postBackSettings.panelsToUpdate != null) {
            // call function here...
        }
    });
};

function AddClickEvent(){
            var CheckAll = jq5("#chkAll").click(function () {
                if (this.checked) {
                    jq5('.chk').attr('checked', this.checked);
                }
                else {
                    jq5('.chk').attr('checked', this.checked = false);
                }
            });
            jq5(".chk").click(function () {
                if (jq5(".chk").length == jq5(".chk:checked").length) {
                    jq5("#chkAll").attr("checked", "checked");
                } else {
                    jq5("#chkAll").removeAttr("checked");
                }
            });
}
```

Comment: solved already, however thank you for your alternate solution

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Just changed the 
`(document).ready(function ()` to `function pageLoad(sender, args)`